# Equations not solvable with Solve function

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to plot b against a with the following equation

```
2 *r* (sin[b]^2) * cos[b] * sin[a + b] == sin[a + 2*b]*((sin[a]^2) + r*(sin[b]^2))
```

with r at >= 0 and let's say <1000

```
Solve[2 cos[b] sin[b]^2 sin[a + b] == (sin[a]^2 + sin[b]^2) sin[a + 2 b], b]
```

However this does give me the error 
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

How would I be able to solve this equation?

Comment: If you don't get your answer solved, try https://math.stackexchange.com/. That forum might be more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to obtain?

[image]

***Edit***

```
sol = FullSimplify@Solve[
    2 r Sin[b]^2 Cos[b] Sin[a + b] == Sin[a + 2 b] (Sin[a]^2 + r Sin[b]^2), b];

Show[Table[Plot[b /. sol[[4]], {a, 3.3, 4.7}],
  {r, {0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2}}],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> None,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Chris, not exactly what I am looking for. However I will post it on mathematica since it is more of a math problem.

Comment: I read your [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3461337/119821) at StackExchange Mathematics.  The above equation seems to be the same as the one posted, but this is as close as I can get.  Perhaps something is missing from the equation.